# Angular 2 ng2-completer get selected item values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

so I am trying a new (for me) autocompleter : 
https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer. Imported it and everything works. :

Now I want to get selected Item values when I choose it :

```
<ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" 
[inputClass]="'form-control form-control-inline'"  [datasource]="getSelectedItemArray?" 
[minSearchLength]="0"></ng2-completer>
```

Selections :

```
 protected searchData = [
    { name: 'Bus UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'Next UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'Lus UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'Mamama UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'Cars UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'Trailers UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'Busses UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'UKUK UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'MAIN UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
    { name: 'LustKK UK LTD', address: 'Example', address2: 'Example2',
      pscode: '8497UK', ccode: '877SAD', veh1: '84A4DA', veh2: '846ASD', trail1: '486XSS', trail2: '8746SS' },
  ];


  constructor(private completerService: CompleterService) {
    this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'name');
  }
```

**In conclusion - I select item from a list - it becomes input value, then I want to get all of that selected item values (name,address, address1....).  How do I reach that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value must be in the model `searchStr`

**UPDATE**

add this to your HTML

```
(selected)="onItemSelected($event)"
```

in your ts :

```
onCountrySelected(selected: CompleterItem) {
        if (selected) {
             console.log(selected.title);
           }       
    }
```

Comment: Yes I get that value, but how do I use it for getting all of the values of that selected item ?

Comment: console.log(selected.originalObject.address);

Comment: that's Goood Enjoy then  ;)